# Download CSV from URL in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I created a web scraper using Puppeteer to extract data from https://www.jobnimbus.com/ and would like to download a CSV file generated by JobNimbus. When I send a GET request to the CSV download URL, I receive **.aspx** file type instead of **.csv**.

JobNimbus requires a login so I'm only showing a sample of the code I'm using:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const download = require("download");

(async () => {
    let url =
        `https://app.jobnimbus.com/ReportDownload.aspx?type=csv&id=${process.env.USER_ID}&rid=null`;
    await download(url, "output");
})();
```

It downloads **ReportDownload.aspx** which appears to be HTML. How do I download this file as CSV? Thank you in advance for your help!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjY9z.png

Comment: that implies that your url is not correct, or it's using a redirect that you have to follow

Comment: URL with actual `USER_ID` value would be helpful to trace the problem